# how to retrieve the number written within bracket of xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I have an issue about xpath formulation

for a xml schema like this :

```
<root>
    <A>
        <B>
            <C>
                <A>
                    <ParentD>
                        <D>
                        <D>
                    </ParentD>
                </A>
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
    <A>
        <B>
            <C>
                <A>
                    <ParentD>
                        <D>
                        <D>
                    </ParentD>
                </A>
            </C>
        </B>
    </A>
```

for the second D of the first bloc A for instance :
    we have the xpath : A[1]/B[1]/C[1]/A[1]/ParentD[1]/D[2]

My question is how to get the number "1" of "A[1]/B[1]/C[1]/***A[*1*]***/ParentD[1]/D[2]" using xpath ?

Comment: What do you mean you want the `1` ? you created the xpath right?

Comment: Why use all of the locators at all? Couldn't you use an xpath like `//ParentD[1]/D[2]` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. But I am faced with a scenario which implies to get the position number of the second A (that I put in bold)  which is presently equals to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count preceding sibling A tags for that A

```
count(//A[1]/B[1]/C[1]/A[ParentD[1]/D[2]]//preceding-sibling::A) + 1
```